# Eclipse- Workspace closed error

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to get the path of my workspace in Eclipse.
I wrote the following code:

```
 IWorkspace myWorkspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
    System.out.println(myWorkspace.getRoot().getFullPath());
```

The problem is that I get a workspace closed exception. How can I solve this ?

Comment: You can only use this code in an Eclipse plugin or Eclipse headless application. You cannot use it in an ordinary Java program.

Comment: I forgot to mention, it's a plugin project :)

Comment: Where in the plugin are you running this?

Comment: I'm running this in a new class

Comment: I mean at what point does this code run? Is it in an `IStartup` extension point for example?

Comment: no, it is in a main class

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) 
 {code}

Comment: You can't use a 'main' class in an Eclipse plugin.

Comment: It's in a new class just to see if it works

Comment: It doesn't matter where it is, a `main` method will not initialize the Eclipse plugin infrastructure and nothing will work properly.

Comment: I ran the code into a plugin class and now I don't see the exception anymore. Instead I get this : "/ " in the console which obviously isn't the required path :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must run this code in Eclipse plugin code. Using a `main` method will not work as the Eclipse/OSGi plugin infrastructure will not be initialized and nothing will work properly.

Secondly `getFullPath()` returns the path relative to the workspace root so it will always be `/` for the root. To get the local file system path use `getLocation()`

Comment: This will give me the path of the project where I run the plugin ?

Comment: It gives you the path of the workspace. Plugins are not part of the workspace, they are in the install directory. If you want to do something like finding resources in your plugin there are other ways of doing that.

Comment: I want to find files in the project where the plugin will run but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: For example, I have in a string variable the file name and I want to search for it in the project and then to go to a certain line there in the file.

Comment: When you use `Run As > Eclipse Application` a new, empty, workspace is created. You can create and search for things in that workspace. If you use `Export > Deployable plug-ins and fragments` you can create a plugin jar which you can install in to your current Eclipse - the current workspace for that will be your development workspace.

Comment: And how can I find files in the project ? I need to find a file which is in a folder and to open it. I don't know the folder only the file name !!

Comment: That is a new question

Comment: And SO is not a code writing service. Look at `IFile`, `IFolder`, `IContainer`, `IWorkspaceRoot`, ....